# generate a list of devices installed in a PC through command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to generate a complete list of devices and drivers installed in a PC which includes the serial number or id of the device through the command line
        driverquery /v /fo csv > drvlist.csv
i used this script but the serial or any id which determines a device unique from the other is not included. Is there any script through command line that outputs a list with serial or device id?

Answer (score 1):

Use Device Console
`devcon findall *`

gives output like this

---

```
USB\VID_04F3&PID_0103&MI_01\7&361A51D9&0&0001               : USB Input Device
STORAGE\VOLUME\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_8GB&REV_1100#78A56NWJSMAL7NX3&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}: Generic volume
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0044&SUBSYS_1426103C&REV_02\3&11583659&0&00: Intel(R) processor DRAM Controller - 0044
ACPI\PNP0C32\2                                              : Direct Application Launch Button
USB\VID_0FCE&PID_017E\YT910AXUJ4                            : ST27i
USB\VID_058F&PID_6387\K1IRYQ8W                              : USB Mass Storage Device
USB\VID_03EB&PID_0902\6&3095C40C&0&1                        : Generic USB Hub
STORAGE\VOLUME\{E316F6E1-1DFD-11E2-A36B-1C659D9277A0}#00000000007E0000: Generic volume
ROOT\MS_AGILEVPNMINIPORT\0000                               : WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
ROOT\LEGACY_TUNEUPUTILITIESDRV\0000                         : TuneUpUtilitiesDrv
ROOT\LEGACY_AMWRTDRV\0000                                   : amwrtdrv
.....
```

For more info go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For download go [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx). Make sure you read comments too.

Comment: Is there any way to have the list using only the command line without using or downloading any third party apps or kit?

Comment: Device console is not directly included in windows as a a normal user has no need of it. Generally developers require it. It is made by Microsoft.  "Windows driver developers and testers can use DevCon to verify that a driver is installed and configured correctly, including the proper INF files, driver stack, driver files, and driver package. You can also use the DevCon commands (enable, disable, install, start, stop, and continue) in scripts to test the driver.

DevCon is a command-line tool that performs device management functions on local computers and remote computers."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WMI queries to achieve what you want.

Specifically, take a look at the [Win32_PnPSignedDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394354(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class.

> SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver

You might want to test the query using [Paessler's WMI Tester](http://www.paessler.com/tools/wmitester) to find out all the column names and make sure you only fetch information from the relevant ones.

This little script should work for your purpose:

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver",,48) 
Dim ctr : ctr = 1
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo ctr : ctr = ctr + 1
    Wscript.Echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceName        : " & objItem.DeviceName
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceClass       : " & objItem.DeviceClass
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceClassGUID       : " & objItem.ClassGuid
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceID      : " & objItem.DeviceID
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceHardwareID  : " & objItem.HardWareID
    Wscript.Echo "DriverVersion     : " & objItem.DriverVersion
    Wscript.Echo "DriverProvider        : " & objItem.DriverProviderName
    Wscript.Echo "DriverDescription : " & objItem.Description
    Wscript.Echo "DeviceManufacturer    : " & objItem.Manufacturer
Next
```

Copy that, save it to a file called `"DeviceQuery.vbs"` and run it using the command:

> cscript DeviceQuery.vbs

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599720/1768141)

Comment: Would this list devices with no installed drivers?