# Windows 7: Modify wireless network adapter parameters via Registry

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On Windows 7, I need to know the registry key path for a wireless network adapter, in order to modify its parameters such as *network mode* (B/G/N), *channel width* etc.

The path can be very different from one network adapter to another. For instance, here's a path of a wireless network adapter with GUID=`34a70820-26ee-41bd-bb6a-073fd4c39622`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0017
```

While with another wireless network adapter, the path may vary as follows:

- instead of `ControlSet002` it can be `ControlSet001`
- instead of `4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318` it can be something else
- instead of `0017` it can be `0007`

How do I tell the exact registry path for a specific wireless network adapter, given its GUID?
Command line based solution is needed (not GUI). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

The GUID you mention in the question is not a GUID associated with a specific wireless adapter.
It [represents the class of network adapter devices that the system supports.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780532(v=ws.10).aspx) The subkeys within it will represent network adapters on the computer. You'll need to iterate through them one by one until you find what you're looking for.

However, the TechNet article says its a bad idea to make any changes here with this warning:

- **Do not change any entries in the Class subkey or any subkey within it. The system configures these subkeys to comply with Plug and Play standards. Changing any data can prevent your computer devices from starting or operating properly.**

I don't know where you got `34a70820-26ee-41bd-bb6a-073fd4c39622`, but as far as I know, you identify hardware using its Hardware IDs which look something like:

```
PCI\VEN_123C&DEV_0012&SUBSYS_123456AA&REV_01
```

You could find those programmatically [using WMI](https://superuser.com/a/794553/167187).